# Eclipse Mars hover over methods is black after update

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-mars

I updated to Eclipse Mars. Now if I hover over methods I have black text on black background. Before updating from Luna I had yellow background, black text. How can I configure this hover over for methods? I am on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best workaround I have is this:

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

before starting eclipse. (You can also do: `SWT_GTK3=0 ./eclipse`)

Alternatively, you can now also do:

```
./eclipse --launcher.GTK_version 2
```

I found all GTK3 modes to be barely usable, and in a mess.

The "dark" (emo) mode still works somewhat, because there seem to be some hardcoded colors somewhere (ouch). I wish they would test better. This is just unusable. And I wish the GNOME people would stop breaking their stuff all the time, too. I hate everything they have been doing the last few years... they are totally designing their UI for a different audience than developers.

When trying out different themes/engines **always restart eclipse completely** (not using the "restart" menu) to make sure to pick up new environment variables etc.

You can set this as default, by adding `export SWT_GTK3=0` into your `$HOME/.profile` which will usually be read on *login* (i.e. this will only be effective if you logout and login again).

Comment: Also try switching between dark and non-dark modes. Is your UI using GTK3, or GTK2?

Comment: I am not sure. In my Appearance Settings I have Configuration of the style of GTK applications both GTK2 and GTK3. Right now I have Raleigh, and oxygen-gtk, respectively for GTK2 and GTK3.

Comment: If all the toolbars and tabs are suddenly twice the size, then you are GTK3... You can also try `SWT_GTK3=1` and check if that has an effect.
Also try different gtk engines. I found *most* to not work well with eclipse, unfortunately.

Comment: After updating Ubuntu a while ago things were suddenly much bigger. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Which theme works with Eclipse and GTK-3? Default works, but the rest of the menu looks like Windows 3.1.

Comment: Didn't find anything working with GTK-3 and Eclipse except for the very default theme, in dark mode. I've disabled GTK-3, and I use Clearlooks.

Comment: I use GTK-2 but it still does not work. I tried with clearance in the system settings. Do I need to set the theme anywhere else?

Comment: I don't know. It worked for me this way, it now uses the same theme as before, and looks like it did before.

Comment: It works with Clearlooks. Had to restart Eclipse. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it only worked while starting up Eclipse and then it changed back to dark background.

Comment: Find details to the GTK3 issue in this Blog: http://javaclipse.blogspot.de/2015/06/mars-on-linux.html

Comment: I added those clause above -  export `SWT_GTK3=01` into my .profile (private account). After logout/login it works fine. Thank for solution.

Comment: I used a more fine-grained approach, with an "eclipse" wrapper shell script in my user's scripts directory to set SWT_GTK3=0 before running the real eclipse.  Same outcome for Eclipse, just another way to achieve it.

Comment: To force **Eclipse Mars** to use GTK 2, instead of exporting `SWT_GTK3=0`, you could also start up Eclipse with `{install_path}/eclipse --launcher.GTK_version 2`. To see the version, in Eclipse go to **Help>About Eclipse>Installation Details>Configuration** Tab, and look for `org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.version`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. so i decided to install eclipse mars using **oomph installer** . guess what !! finally i have my eclipse without any GTK 3 problems.

Give it a try there is much more what oomph offers.

I'm using **Fedora 22 Workstation with GNome**